# Why doesn't CSS transition get applied?

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I've built a small stacked bar visual just using floated `divs` that underneath is bound to some data using `knockout`. What I want to be able to do is to animate changes in the size of these stacks when the data changes.

I've managed to do this in the general case, so of the 4 bars that I've got, 3 of them transition correctly. The problem is my final bar seems to ignore the transition and instantly re-sizes and I can't understand why. Here's a picture of the before/during/after states:

[image]

The way that I've defined this transition is simply via css

```
-webkit-transition: width 1s;
transition: width 1s;
```

The width of the bars is a computed value, calculating the percentage of items, so each bar should have it's width defined as a percentage. Although the red bar is calculated differently to the other 3 bars, I don't see why that should affect the transition.

What I find quite strange, is that if I modify the width through the developer console for example, then the bar does correctly animate. I'm wondering if anyone can suggest why this might be the case?

```js
var vm = (function generateModel() {
    var data = {
        name: "Sign-off",
        id: "XX",
        values: [{ text: "Signed-off", count: 150, color: "#5fb5cc" }, 
                 { text: "Submitted", count: 90, color: "#75d181" }, 
                 { text: "Not Submitted", count: 75, color: "#f8a25b" }
                ],
        aggregates: {
            count: 650
        }
    };

    // Create a view model directly from the data which we will update
    var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

    // Add a computed value to calculate percentage
    vm.values().forEach(function (d) {
        d.percentage = ko.computed(function () {
            return d.count() / vm.aggregates.count() * 100;
        });
    });
    
    // Create a 
    vm.allValues = ko.computed(function() {
        var values = [];
        var count = 0;
        var total = vm.aggregates.count();
        
        debugger;
        
        // Add each of these results into those that will be returned
        vm.values().forEach(function(d) { 
           values.push(d); 
            count += d.count();
        });
        
        // Create an other category for everything else
        values.push({
            text: ko.observable("Other"),
            count: ko.observable(total - count),
            percentage: ko.observable((total - count) / total * 100),
            color: ko.observable("#ff0000")
        });
        
        return values;
    });

    return vm;
})();

ko.applyBindings(vm);

setTimeout(function() {
   vm.values()[0].count(90);
    vm.values()[1].count(40);
    vm.values()[2].count(35);
    vm.aggregates.count(3550);
}, 3000);
```

```css
body {
    background: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}
.spacer {
    height: 230px;
}
.cards {
    float: right;
}
/* Small Card */
 .card {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width:398px;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 5px 15px 5px;
    font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.title {
    color: rgb(105, 161, 36);
    font-size: 16px;
}
.states {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.state {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgb(67, 88, 98);
    padding: 0px 5px 2px 5px;
    clear: both;
}
.circle {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1px 5px 5px 0px;
}
.value {
    float: right;
}
.graph {
    padding: 10px 5px 0px 5px;
}
.bar {
    float: left;
    height: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: width 10s;
    transition: width 10s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
<div class="card">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="graph" data-bind="foreach: allValues">
            <div class="bar" data-bind="style: { background: color, width: percentage() + '%' }"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like a css problem . it seems like the red bar is calculate as 100% - the sum of final sizes of the 3 bars instead of 100 - the current sizes of the sum of the 3 bars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the first 3 are based on object references that don't change, knockout is preserving the actual `<div>` that's been rendered.

For the final bar, each time `allValues` is evaluated, it's pushing a brand new object into the returned array.  I would assume that since knockout sees that as a new object, it re-renders the div from scratch, rather than updating existing bindings.

You'll need to rework your model slightly to hold an actual object for that final value so that you can then update the observables on it in the same way.

Here's a fixed version using a static object for the "other" value:

```js
var vm = (function generateModel() {
    var data = {
        name: "Sign-off",
        id: "XX",
        values: [{ text: "Signed-off", count: 150, color: "#5fb5cc" }, 
                 { text: "Submitted", count: 90, color: "#75d181" }, 
                 { text: "Not Submitted", count: 75, color: "#f8a25b" }
                ],
        aggregates: {
            count: 650
        }
    };

    // Create a view model directly from the data which we will update
    var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

    // Add a computed value to calculate percentage
    vm.values().forEach(function (d) {
        d.percentage = ko.computed(function () {
            return d.count() / vm.aggregates.count() * 100;
        });
    });
    
    //Create a static "others" object
    vm.other = {
        text: ko.observable("Other"),
        count: ko.computed(function() { 
            var total = vm.aggregates.count();
            var count = 0;
            vm.values().forEach(function(d) { count += d.count(); });
            return total - count;
        }),
        percentage: ko.computed(function(d, b) {
            var total = vm.aggregates.count();
            var count = 0;
            vm.values().forEach(function(d) { count += d.count(); });
            return (total - count) / total * 100;
        }),
        color: ko.observable("#ff0000")
    };
  
    // Create a 
    vm.allValues = ko.computed(function() {
        var values = [];
        var count = 0;
        var total = vm.aggregates.count();
        
        debugger;
        
        // Add each of these results into those that will be returned
        vm.values().forEach(function(d) { 
           values.push(d); 
            count += d.count();
        });
              
        // and push static object in instead of creating a new one
        values.push(vm.other);
        
        return values;
    });

    return vm;
})();

ko.applyBindings(vm);

setTimeout(function() {
   vm.values()[0].count(90);
    vm.values()[1].count(40);
    vm.values()[2].count(35);
    vm.aggregates.count(3550);
}, 3000);
```

```css
body {
    background: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}
.spacer {
    height: 230px;
}
.cards {
    float: right;
}
/* Small Card */
 .card {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width:398px;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 5px 15px 5px;
    font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.title {
    color: rgb(105, 161, 36);
    font-size: 16px;
}
.states {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.state {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgb(67, 88, 98);
    padding: 0px 5px 2px 5px;
    clear: both;
}
.circle {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1px 5px 5px 0px;
}
.value {
    float: right;
}
.graph {
    padding: 10px 5px 0px 5px;
}
.bar {
    float: left;
    height: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: width 10s;
    transition: width 10s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
<div class="card">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="graph" data-bind="foreach: allValues">
            <div class="bar" data-bind="style: { background: color, width: percentage() + '%' }"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even better - you've saved me having to figure out how to do it :) Good catch, thank you.

Comment: @Ian Even better, based on looking at this, I've actually got an understanding of what the never-before-used-by-me mapping plugin actually does :)

Comment: Mapping us a great plugin, just it's difficult to update without breaking existing bindings (kinda like this question but actual listeners will break). There is a merge plugin I'm trying to use, just working through a bug in it with the author.

Comment: @Ian Right.  I think it was the updates that's confused me in the past with the mapping plugin.  One final point - you've put `percentage: ko.computed(function(d, b) {`.  Looks like `d` and `b` aren't used, is that just a typo, or can computed's take parameters in that fashion?  If so, what are they?  Never seen that before, and the docs don't seem to cover it?

Comment: Oops, sorry. That was a copy paste issue. I was hoping to get the context to read the other computed value 'count' so I didn't need to do it again but couldn't access it. Think you can with a custom binding though