# Transitions between different knockout components

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I'm trying to apply `CSS` transitions as I switch between knockout components but I'm not having much joy in achieving this. Essentially I want to have a `div` with a fixed width, but the internal content of which will change. As it does this I want to be able to transition the re-sizing of the element.

```js
ko.components.register("big", {
    viewModel: function (vm) {
        this.items = vm.value.items;
    },
    template: '<div class="big box" data-bind="foreach: items"><p class="item" data-bind="text: name"></p></div>'
});

ko.components.register("small", {
    viewModel: function (vm) {        
        this.items = vm.value.items;
    },
    template: '<div class="small box" data-bind="foreach: items"><span class="item" data-bind="text: name"></span></div>'
});






var vm = {};
vm.componentName = ko.observable("small");
vm.items = ko.observableArray([{ name: "A" }, { name: "B" }, { name: "C" }]);
ko.applyBindings(vm);

setInterval(function() {
    if(vm.componentName() === "small") { vm.componentName("big"); }
    else { vm.componentName("small"); }
}, 3000);
```

```css
.box {
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s;
    transition: height 2s;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    transition: width 2s;
}
.big {
    border: thin solid black;
}
.small {
    border: thin solid black;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.item {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="component: { name: componentName, params: { value: $data } }">
</div>
```

So I've asked something vaguely related [Why doesn't CSS transition get applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867780/why-doesnt-css-transition-get-applied) where I learnt that the DOM is being re-constructed for the new value (in this case new template) and hence CSS transitions don't apply.

The solution there was simple (ensure you bind to the same thing repeatedly). But for components, I really don't want to combine two templates together just so I can get transitions. Is there another way I can achieve this?

Comment: I have a half-baked idea that after rendering, you could get the size of the templated div, then upon changing, force the new div to that size, *then* remove the size restriction, which would trigger the transition. A little tricky.

Comment: @RoyJ yeah, I'm trying to modify sroes answer to achieve that sort of idea. Just struggling getting jQuery doing what I expected at the moment but you can see progress thus far here http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/mjhynt2m/

Comment: @RoyJ: I think at the moment I'm struggling to select the new element for some reason.

Comment: Please see my completely updated answer. It works!

Comment: @RoyJ: I will take a look hopefully next week when I'm in the office. Thanks Roy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually switching the component meaning the DOM is being re-constructed, so I don't see a way to animate using CSS.

What you can do is build your own binding handler which does the animating for you using Javascript:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.animatingComponent = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var componentName = value.name;
        // create a new observable so we can delay the moment ko's component 
        // binding builds the new component
        var actualComponentName = ko.observable(componentName());
        componentName.subscribe(function(newComponent) {
            $(element).hide(500, function() {
                actualComponentName(newComponent);
                $(element).show(500);
           });
        });

        ko.bindingHandlers.component.init(element, function() { 
            return { name: actualComponentName, params: value.params}; 
        }, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
};

ko.components.register("big", {
    viewModel: function (vm) {
        this.items = vm.value.items;
    },
    template: '<div class="big box" data-bind="foreach: items"><p class="item" data-bind="text: name"></p></div>'
});

ko.components.register("small", {
    viewModel: function (vm) {        
        this.items = vm.value.items;
    },
    template: '<div class="small box" data-bind="foreach: items"><span class="item" data-bind="text: name"></span></div>'
});


var vm = {};
vm.componentName = ko.observable("small");
vm.items = ko.observableArray([{ name: "A" }, { name: "B" }, { name: "C" }]);
ko.applyBindings(vm);

setInterval(function() {
    if(vm.componentName() === "small") { vm.componentName("big"); }
    else { vm.componentName("small"); }
}, 3000);
```

```css
.box {
    width: 200px;
}
.big {
    border: thin solid black;
}
.small {
    border: thin solid black;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.item {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="animatingComponent: { name: componentName, params: { value: $data } }">
</div>
```

Comment: Right I see, that's not quite the desired affect I want, but I think I can work with it.

Comment: Since components don't know anything about each other, I don't think it's possible to apply transitions using CSS

Comment: I see what you're doing here... I'm trying to modify the example slightly (so rather than fade, it just changes height) but am struggling slightly. Understand that pure CSS isn't going to work. Got any suggestions? http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/mjhynt2m/2/

Comment: Sorry, that was a really bad fiddle. Here's a better attempt http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/mjhynt2m/3/. I'm confused as to how you fade the element out, then back in... when it's dealing with the same element? Issue I have is I can't select the "new" height of the div

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/smsu42zs/. It seems you first have to give KO some time to construct the component before you can get the height.

Comment: I spotted that same delay required and implemented in exactly the same way. Almost managed to get what I wanted. Only difficult I've had is I can't clear the in-line height and get the new calculated height again (even with another timeout), so I need to use the height of the children... but that has some padding issues http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/mjhynt2m/4/

Comment: Here the top margin of the first child takes up margin outside of the parent. Maybe just fix it with some css: `.box > :first-child { margin-top: 0; }`

Answer (score 1):

It only took most of the day, but I got the transition to work. I have a variable that remembers the last display size (which is where it will start when the component changes). When the component changes, I set visibility to hidden and sizes to default so I can get the intended size of the div. Then I size it back to the last display size and make it visible, then size it to the new size, and the transition happens.

Note that I also had to change the CSS a bit.

```js
ko.components.register("big", {
viewModel: function (vm) {
    this.items = vm.value.items;
},
template: '<div class="big box" data-bind="style:$root.boxSize, foreach: items, sizeGet:$root.boxSize"><p class="item" data-bind="text: name"></p></div>'
});

ko.components.register("small", {
viewModel: function (vm) {
    this.items = vm.value.items;
},
template: '<div class="small box" data-bind="style:$root.boxSize, foreach: items, sizeGet:$root.boxSize"><span class="item" data-bind="text: name"></span></div>'
});


var unclipped;
ko.bindingHandlers.sizeGet = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var sizer = valueAccessor();
    sizer({
        height: '',
        width: '',
        visibility: 'hidden'
    });
    var nextUnclipped = {
        height: element.scrollHeight + 'px',
        width: element.scrollWidth + 'px',
        visibility: 'visible'
    };

    if (unclipped) sizer(unclipped);
    unclipped = nextUnclipped;
    setTimeout(function () {
        sizer(unclipped);
    }, 0);
}
};

var vm = (function () {
var activeComponent = ko.observable('small'),
    defaultSize = {
        width: '',
        height: ''
    },
    boxSize = ko.observable(defaultSize);

return {
    componentName: activeComponent,
    boxSize: boxSize,
    items: ko.observableArray([{
        name: "A"
    }, {
        name: "Big"
    }, {
        name: "Cat"
    }, {
        name: "Dropping"
    }])
};
}());
ko.applyBindings(vm);

var i = setInterval(function () {
if (vm.componentName() === "small") {
    vm.componentName("big");
} else {
    vm.componentName("small");
}
}, 3000);

setTimeout(clearInterval.bind(null, i), 45000);
```

```css
.box {
    width:200px;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s, width 2s;
    transition: height 2s, width 2s;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.big {
    border: thin solid black;
}
.small {
    border: thin solid black;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.item {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="component: { name: componentName, params: { value: $data } }">
</div>
```