# Can Knockout.js bindings apply to container tags AND descendants both?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Let me setup the question with a simple case.

I have an HTML table, the rows of which are controlled by an observableArray. It works great.

If the observableArray has zero elements in it however, I want a single row to say so.  I tried this markup, which "kind of" works:

```
<tbody data-bind="if: $root.data.contacts().length == 0">
    <tr>
        <td>There are no contacts specified yet.</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

<tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.data.contacts">
        SNIP - a tbody with the rows is here when elements > zero
</tbody>
```

When I say "kind of", I mean VISIBLY.  It really does show up at zero elements and really does go away at > zero elements like what you would expect. However when you open the DOM inspector (dev tools) and look at the DOM in memory, you find that there are TWO *tbody* sections, not one. Now one *tbody* is always empty of course, but <del>two *tbody* tags is not HTML5 correct, so this must be fixed</del> this is not the desired markup.

Being a Knockout newbie, I tried to fix this problem with a virtual element:

```
<!-- ko if: $root.data.contacts().length == 0 -->
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>There are no contacts specified yet.</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work for our build process: we minify HTML prior to compression and comments get eliminated.

I was under the impression that KO bindings applied to the CONTAINER ELEMENT ITSELF as well as descendants, but this seems to not be so.  Is there a way to tell KO to apply to container elements as well as children, or do I need to change the markup in some way OTHER THAN a virtual container?

Comment: What problem you face if your have two `tbody` tags inside table?

Comment: Well, apparently none. I thought multiple <tbody> elements was illegal, but a reading of the spec shows that multiples are allowed.  My question still stands about binding to the container AS WELL as children, but my assumption about HTML5 correctness is wrong.  I will update.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tbody-element

Comment: The `if` binding controls the *contained* elements, not the element the binding is on. You can see that on the doc page if you inspect the live demo. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html
If you wanted to use `if`, you could have two complete tables, each wrapped in an `if`-bound div.

Comment: That would produce two divs always, which, div being a block level element, might negatively impact the markup depending on the use case. Your use of the new template tag markup in the answer below is always clean, no orphaned elements. The fact that you can have a single observable string control (possibly large) sections of your markup is a paradigm shift in design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you, my first choice would be virtual tags for an `if` binding. But since that's not an option, how about swappable templates?

```js
var vm = {
  contacts: ko.observableArray()
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

setTimeout(function() {
  vm.contacts(['One', 'Two', 'Three']);
}, 2500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<template id="empty-body">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>There are no contacts specified yet.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</template>
<template id="normal-body">
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: contacts">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text:$data"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</template>
<table data-bind="template: contacts().length === 0 ? 'empty-body' : 'normal-body'"></table>
```

Comment: oh my ! i'm flabbergasted @roy . really liked the thought +1 (tough i tought about templates but `swappable` templates is classic ). cheers mate

Comment: @supercool We don't normally think of the template name as a variable, but it can be an observable. I've done this with components a couple of times.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023028/transitions-between-different-knockout-components
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860980/knockout-components-or-templates-performance-gains

Comment: I did not understand this at first, but 8 hours of sleep helps all things! The relevant bit from KO's template documentation is this: "Shorthand syntax: If you just supply a string value, KO will interpret this as the ID of a template to render." So that makes it clear why this solution is so brilliant. Kudos @Roy - that's really great stuff. The answer to the main question is "No, KO binds only to descendants and there is no way to make it not do so", and "Yes, there is a way to change the markup to produce the desired effect."  Thanks, great answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [Knockout-Repeat binding](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat) applies the binding to the element itself. It does so by using a node preprocessor to wrap elements with the `repeat` binding in virtual (comment-based) elements at run time.

```js
var vm = {
  contacts: ko.observableArray()
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

setTimeout(function() {
  vm.contacts(['One', 'Two', 'Three']);
}, 2500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mbest/knockout-repeat/master/knockout-repeat.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="repeat: !contacts().length && 1">
    <tr>
      <td>There are no contacts specified yet.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody data-bind="repeat: contacts().length && 1" data-repeat-bind="foreach: contacts">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text:$data"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: that's a very useful project - thanks for posting it.  In fact I am questioning if your answer is actually a better answer to my question.  Template flipping (currently the selected answer) has not been a 100% walk in the park in the past few days. The expectation of template flipping is that only ONE template be in the DOM at a time (remove old, add new), but I have proven that actually you can't count on that. Due to the uncontrollable order of subscriber execution, a "add new, remove old" case is possible which can play havoc with bindings. Will study and possibly change answer.