# Can knockout.js if binding be used to remove the element?

Tags: knockout.js

Suppose I have following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="group-of-things">
     <span>thing #1</span>
     <span>thing #2</span>
     <span data-bind="if: showThing3">thing #3</span>
</div>
```

now suppose I have a CSS that rounds corners on the last child of the `group-of-things`:

```
.group-of-things > *:last-child { border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0 }
```

The problem is that when `showThing3` turns false - `thing #3` is hidden (content is removed), but the containing (third) `span` remains in the DOM, as a result `thing #2` does *not* get rounded corners.

This can be solved by using containerless binding (`<!-- ko if: showThing3 -->`), but I would like to avoid using containerless bindings because comments are being stripped off by the pipeline I have no control over.

It maybe possible to tweak CSS rule to only consider children that are visible (e.g. I could use `css` binding to add `hidden` class on the hidden element).

Is there a more elegant solution that would actually remove `span` in question from the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32878282/1287183) a similar question by suggesting the [Knockout-Repeat binding](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat), which applies the binding to the element itself. At run-time, it wraps the element in a virtual (comment-based) element.

```js
var vm = {
    showThing3: ko.observable(true)
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

setTimeout(function () {
    vm.showThing3(false);
}, 2500);
```

```css
.group-of-things > * { color: white; padding: 2px; background: blue; }
.group-of-things > *:last-child { border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mbest/knockout-repeat/master/knockout-repeat.js"></script>

<div class="group-of-things">
    <span>thing #1</span>
    <span>thing #2</span>
    <span data-bind="repeat: showThing3() && 1">thing #3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good solution. I wish OOB `if` would do that. I think that current semantic of `if` is counter-intuitive, many developers expect that `if`-ed element will be controlled, no the content of the element.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use an observable array of things?

```
<div data-bind="foreach: things" class="group-of-things">
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
</div>

<script>
    model.things = ko.observableArray(["thing #1", "thing #2", "thing #3"]);
    ... 
    model.things.remove( "thing #3" );
```

Comment: I simplified the code for the demo purposes. Your answer is valid though for what I've asked. Actual code has heterogeneous list.

Answer (score 0):

A binding that could remove the element it's attached to would not be very useful as it wouldn't be able to add itself back. Normally, you would solve this problem by using the containerless bindings. However, if that's not an option you have to get creative.

- You could try storing your template as a javascript string with
  browserify. Doubt this pipeline would be able to mess with it then.
  Something like
  [readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options)
  could be used to do this. Knockout even has an
  [example](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html#note-integrating-with-browserify)
  of this approach.
- You could create a custom binding that you would be put on the
  group-of-things div. It would manually add/remove the "thing #3"
  span.