# How can I set observable routes where the content comes from a template when using knockout.js and Sammy.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, routes, sammy.js

I am trying to make a single page application using Sammy.js for routes.
[This](http://pastebin.com/MEXWzFWm) is the JS:

```
var galleryTemplateUrl = "templates/galleryTemplate.html";
var registerTemplateUrl = "templates/registerTemplate.html";
var containerId = '#container';
var containerElement = $(containerId);

var app = new Sammy(containerId, function() {
    var self = this;
    self.get('#/Gallery', function() {
        containerElement.html("");
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: galleryTemplateUrl
        }).done(function  (result) {
            containerElement.append(result);
            ko.applyBindings(testView(),containerElement[0]);
        })
    });

    self.get('#/Register', function(){
        containerElement.html("");
       $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: registerTemplateUrl
       }).done(function  (result) {

          containerElement.append(result);
       })
    });
});

app.run('#/Gallery');
```

The rest is pretty straightforward. I have a container div in my HTML and the templates are HTML files with some data-bindings in them.

**PROBLEM**: Once I launch the application the bindings are successfully read the first time I load them however if I change to the next route and come back to the previous route the bindings no longer apply.

I think I'm supposed to reset the function in the ko.applyBinding but I have no idea how.

I've tried  adding ko.clearNode() before I make a new AJAX request however that didn't work as well.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** I found a way around my problem but it's probably not the "right" solution. Basically I put my container div in another div. Then every time I added a template to my container div I deleted it and remade it with a different id.

**Edit:** The root of the problem seems to be that if cleanNode() is used on the same element which is passed to new Sammy then cleanNode will shut down Sammy as well.Basically don't use cleanNode on the element Sammy is running.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use Knockout to manage the DOM. That probably means making a [component](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) (or maybe just a [template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)) for each route-page, and having the router activate the appropriate one.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32824387/392102) may be helpful.