# knockoutjs re-bind when document reload by ajax

Tags: ajax, mobile, knockout.js

I use a mobile UI Framework which load page by ajax. when change page it remove page dom by $.remove();

and I use knockoutjs to bind data in every page.

the problem is when page A is removed. ko not remove. then I change to A again(From page B). It can not applybinds agin.

Also I try ko.cleanNode(),then rebind
but it do not clear foreach nodes,so how can I rebind ko, when document reload by ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Stop using jQuery to manipulate the DOM. That is Knockout's only job. Knockout is not a tool to bind data, Knockout is a tool to manage the DOM. Knockout provides tools to do things like swapping out pages (see [Swappable Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32824387/392102), for example)

If you are using `cleanNode`, you are doing something wrong. If you need to change out your viewmodel entirely, *the viewmodel itself can be an observable*.

```
vm = ko.observable(someInitialVm);

ko.applyBindings(vm);

//...at some point...
vm(aWholeDifferentVm);
```

You can do that. Focus on your viewmodel. Leave the DOM to Knockout.